Why is Chess Position Trainer slow in Windows 11?
I'm running Chess Position Trainer in Windows 11 through a VM on a MacBook air with the m2 processor.  The animation of the pieces is incredibly slow and the program overall is slow.  Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

I would guess that it's slow because you're running it on a VM. It's hard to say for sure, though.
